# Paste Special Values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a range consisting of 3 columns and 2 (or more) rows.
The middle column contains a formula: `=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1,","))`

The script needs to move (cut) that range onto another sheet as ***values***, not formulas.

Does google-apps-script have a means of doing "PasteSpecial - Values"?

Here is the line I'm currently using:

```
sheet1.getRange("F1:H3").moveTo(sheet2.getRange("A1"));
```

Can anyone tell me how I can lock those values in before they move onto sheet2 ?

*(FYI: this requires a code solution only)*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just as an alternative, you can use [copyTo() with advanced arguments](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo%28Range,Object%29) to copy values only. To mimic the effect of moveTo(), you would still need to clear the source range.

Also, if it's easier, getRange() accepts a string reference that includes the sheet name. So:

```
function moveValuesOnly() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getRange('Sheet1!F1:H3');
  source.copyTo(ss.getRange('Sheet2!A1'), {contentsOnly: true});
  source.clear();
}
```

Comment: DUDE!!!! Wow AdamL, I can't even begin to tell you how relieved I am to be able to incorporate THAT into my code! And it works like a charm! You saved my day bro! Thank you SO much! Plus.... I can even understand it!!! :P  Thank you. Really.

Comment: I just wanted to say THANK YOU again. I've been using this nugget of code regularly ever since you were kind enough to provide it. "Teach a man to fish......."

Comment: No problem mate, glad it helped. I wish I could give credit to whomever might have posted about this method in the dim dark past, but I honestly don't remember.

Comment: @user2579734 - Please do not edit an existing answer in order to ask a question. That is what the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) option is for! ;-)

Comment: Also a note to readers: If you want to be selective about what you "clear" from the cell (e.g., contents but not formatting), you can use the `clear(options)` method with this script, found here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range Thanks @AdamL for sharing this really useful answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

Use getValues() on the source range and setValues() on the destination. You must ensure the ranges are the same dimensions. You can then clear() the source.

Here's a utility function that does the job. It's also [available as a gist](https://gist.github.com/mogsdad/5415837). Note that it takes Range Objects as parameters.

#### Code

```
/**
 * Move all values from source range to destination range. Upon
 * completion, source range will be cleared. Source values will
 * be moved into a destination range starting at the "top left"
 * of the destination range, using the dimensions of the source
 * range. This is a blind copy, with no overwrite test.
 *
 * @param {Range} source Range Object to take values from.
 * @param {Range} destination Range Object to receive values.
 *
 * @returns nothing
 */
function moveRange(source,destination) {
  var sourceSheet = source.getSheet();
  var destSheet = destination.getSheet();
  var sourceData = source.getValues();
  var dest = destSheet.getRange(
    destination.getRow(),        // Top row of destination
    destination.getColumn(),     // left col of destination
    sourceData.length,           // # rows in source
    sourceData[0].length);       // # cols in source (elements in first row)
  dest.setValues(sourceData);
  source.clear();
}
```

#### Test Function

A successful test will clear the entire source range, and its contents will appear in the destination range as values only. The destination dimensions will match the source dimensions, regardless of what's provided as destination - it's only the top-left corner that anchors the move.

```
function test_moveRange() {
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  var destSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[1];

  var source = sourceSheet.getRange("A7:C10");
  var destination = destSheet.getRange("C4:H2");
  moveRange(source,destination);
}
```

Comment: I did try that (and I just tried it again). I receive the following... "TypeError: Cannot find function getValues in object Sheet".  So I guess my question now expands to include: Why does getRange work in the same sheet object but getValues doesn't? (geez... just when I thought that I was getting the hang of this :/ )

Comment: You've got to check what Class the Method belongs to, and make sure you pair them up correctly. The `getValues()` method belongs to Class Range, not Sheet, but `getRange()` *is* a Sheet method.

Comment: Ok, so now I'm really confused. I need to be able to specify which sheet is the source and which sheet is the destination. With getRange I can do that. So how do I specify sheet source/destination using getValues? (I swear, if I see another red error message.... my head is going to implode! Why "implode" as opposed to "explode", you might be asking yourself; well, explode belongs to Class Anger. While implode belongs to Class Fury. It's all very logical)

Comment: See the update, with a full working function. Once you have a source range, you use `source.getValues()` to grab the contents (values only) as a two-dimensional array. Then use `dest.setValues(values2set)` to put that array into the destination. Remember that `getRange()` gives you a Range Object, which is NOT the content of the range-of-cells.