# Copying values from Google sheet, add time stamp, prevent duplicates

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using Kimono to scrape a site that lists active development permits. For a one off data scrape it's fine, the problem is that there is no way of sorting new data. Every time Kimono scrapes it updates the entire array.

This is what the sheet currently looks like
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BH8ESAHQJrog6x8nRBOpgBN-nTN1_aDY7wr8W_YYet0/edit#gid=1865015934

The first sheet is automatically populated and overwritten by Kimono. It seems like the most logical way of making this work would be to copy the values to another sheet, adding a time stamp when this happens and then preventing duplicate values from being posted.

Following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090447/paste-special-values-google-apps-script) is was able to muster this code

I've got the copying part down with the following:

```
function moveValuesOnly() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var source = ss.getRange('Building Permits!A1:D');
   source.copyTo(ss.getRange('Sheet2!A1'), {contentsOnly: true});
   source.clear();
}
```

What I am trying to figure out is how to prevent duplicates based on the URL value.

I know that it is right in front of me, but I'm drawing a blank on how to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

This Google documentation article on removing duplicates is very well written, so I won't duplicate it: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/removing_duplicates

It has exactly what you need. Read the later part of the article where it talks about how to check duplicates not for the entire row, but specific columns in that row. Once you understand that, your problem is straightforward to solve. Just use 2 arrays, to hold the contents of the rows from the 2 sheets as in the example they've given. compare the first column value of the current row. if it matches, don't copy the row over.

note: this works only when you copy row-by-row into the target sheet, not the entire range as your'e doing right now. But that's unavoidable.