# Paste Special Values -Google App for google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have two sheets. One is source and other destination.

I have used following script from another discussion:
[Paste Special Values (google-apps-script)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090447/paste-special-values-google-apps-script)

With minor amendments, the script is shown below:

```
function moveValuesOnly() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var source = ss.getRange('sourceSheet!A2:M38');
source.copyTo(ss.getRange('destinationSheet!B2'), {contentsOnly: true});
  }
```

It works fine and taking values from the source file and paste it in destination.

I need that the function could be repeated automatically for every new entry in the source

After the first transfer to destination, I refresh the cells at source and enter new data.
I want that it should also move to new cell in destination instead of overwriting the previous entries. Every next entry should be stored in new column(or row) in the destination.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your data looks like, whether you're wanting to clear out the source sheet each time or whether the data is coming from a form.  In any case this function will determine where your last row of data is on the destination sheet and pop the source data (which is always A2:M38?) straight below there.

```
function moveValuesOnly() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Source sheet name');
var ds = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('destination sheet name');

var source = ss.getRange('sourceSheet!A2:M38');
var dslen = ds.getDataRange().getLastRow();
var i = dslen + 1

source.copyTo(ds.getRange("B" + i), {contentsOnly: true});
  }
```